# VSTS DB GDR - Why are references unresolved within the same database?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference, gdr

I am playing around with the Visual Studio Team Suite Database Edition GDR, and I've imported several of our databases.

I have literally thousands of warnings, most of which are unresolved references.

I understand when we don't have *SchemaName.dbo.TableName* for external references, but why would there be warnings (even errors) when the Table exists in the local context (with all the referenced columns) and it's fully qualified?

What am I missing?  There are so many of these, it has to be simple -- like me, apparently ;-)

Any guidance much appreciated - Jonathan

Comment: Is this a case of each 'failing' schema being referenced unsuccessfully by the others?

If so, how do you get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to the GDR myself. These two links look like they might be helpful, sorry i can't explain it fully myself. There is a known issue in an older release. Also there will be errors if temp tables or TVP's are being referenced.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031142904/http://geekswithblogs.net/dtotzke/archive/2009/03/31/130556.aspx)
Potential solution -
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gertd/file-level-build-warning-suppression-in-the-gdr)